# Detect version of tomcat when WAR file starts (possibly stop it if it is not on the recommended version)

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, war

I have a java web application (WAR) in which I would like the possibility to detect which version of tomcat is starting it. It is possible to do so?

If so I would also like to look into how to stop the application for a non-suitable tomcat.

### my (naive) Google search didn't help me

Hatim

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new Listener, that implements the `ServletContextListener` interface, and add it to web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>cl.tests.servlet.MyServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Then, on the Listener, find the server name/version, and throw a runtime error if it's not what you want

```
package cl.tests.servlet;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

public class MyServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener{

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {

            // Find where am I running... 
        String str1 = arg0.getServletContext().getServerInfo();
        System.out.println("Detected runtime : " + str1);       

        if (str1.indexOf("Apache Tomcat/7") < 0)
            throw new RuntimeException("Not a Tomcat 7 server.");       
    }
}
```

This will stop the entire WAR from starting.

Answer (score 1):

Straight from [Tomcat FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Miscellaneous#Q4):

> **How to I get Tomcat's version number?**
>
> `javax.servlet.ServletContext.getServerInfo();`
>
> Starting with Tomcat 5.0.28 - there is now a version.sh (or
>   version.bat) program in the bin directory. It will print the version
>   number of Tomcat to Standard output.